# How do you save items from a CheckBoxList in a FormView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource, formview, checkboxlist

I am using a **CheckBoxList** inside of a **FormView** with an **ObjectDataSource**. In order to bind the selected values to the **CheckBoxList** I am using the *FormView_DataBound* event to find the **CheckBoxList** and set the selected items. This works fine.

Now saving these values is becoming problematic. Is it possible to use the **ObjectDataSource** to update these values, or do I have to save them after the **ObjectDataSource** saves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this code in formview inserting event... Iterate checkbox list and add selected item in datatable and pass to your BLL

```
CheckBoxList chklRoles = (CheckBoxList)frm.FindControl("chklRoles");
    foreach (ListItem liRole in chklRoles.Items)
    {
        if (liRole.Selected)
        {
            SecurityDS.SC_RoleRow drwRoles = dtblRoles.NewSC_RoleRow();
            drwRoles.Name = liRole.Value;
            drwRoles.IsActive = false;
            dtblRoles.Rows.Add(drwRoles);
        }
    }
    e.Values["userRole"] = dtblRoles;
```

**ASPX page code**.. parameter type

```
<InsertParameters>

                    <asp:Parameter Name="userRole" Type="Object" />
                </InsertParameters>
```

and then iterate datatable in your BLL and save into DB accordingly